# Kitkat appdrawer hide apps and create folders

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat, app-drawer

Back in Jellybean you where able to sort the apps in the app drawer, even make folders. In KitKat it seems that this feature is removed. Is there a rom or app that can bring this back?

Comment: What device? Is it Stock Kitkat? You could try Nova or another launcher that has this function. What launcher are you using?

Comment: found a great launcher in the play store, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.ndsc.kitkatlauncher :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has never been a feature of the stock launcher. Perhaps you were using a phone on Jellybean where the manufacturer had replaced the stock launcher with their own launcher, which had this feature.

Since Android supports third-party launchers, just install a launcher (home screen) app which supports this feature. There are many to choose from.